# Waiting for a trigger in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, events, eventtrigger

I have a script in python with the library keyboard and i have `while True` loop   but this loop is following by a `if keyboard.is_pressed('esc')` and i would like to know if there is something more smart to wait the action and restart it after the program finished ? because the while loop use a lot the CPU :/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i fianlly used a `keyboard.wait('esc')` to trigger de while loop only after the key is pressed and not everytime